# Odoo9: NotImplementedError: Type de rapport inconnu : "webkit"

Tags: webkit, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

Please, i couldnt implement a webkit report on Odoo 9.

Every time that i press on "PRINT", i got this error:

```
2015-12-18 10:24:33,999 5743 ERROR seetek openerp.service.report:   Exception: Type de rapport inconnu : "webkit"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/report.py", line 94, in go
 result, format = openerp.report.render_report(cr, uid, ids, object, datas, context)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 22, in render_report
 return registry['ir.actions.report.xml'].render_report(cr, uid, ids, name, data, context)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 197, in render_report
 return new_report.create(cr, uid, res_ids, data, context)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 370, in create
 raise NotImplementedError(_('Unknown report type: %s') % report_type)
 NotImplementedError: Type de rapport inconnu : "webkit"
```

Need your help guys!!
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try This may it will help you, in this you have to explicitly define the parser path. See this example, (parser) attribute:

```
 <report id="report_demo"
        name="demo.module"
        auto="False"
        model="model.name"
        string="Packing Slip"
    parser="<module_name>.<folder_name>.<py file>.<parsar class>"
    header="False"
        report_type="webkit"
/>
```

see this discussion: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2334

Comment: Thanks a lot friend but i am having the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

**Odoo 9 Report**

Every report must be declared by a report action.

For simplicity, a shortcut `<report>` element is available to define a report, rather than have to set up the action and its surroundings manually. That `<report>` can take the following attributes:

**id** : 
the generated record's external id

**name (mandatory)** : 
only useful as a mnemonic/description of the report when looking for one in a list of some sort

**model (mandatory)**:
the model your report will be about

**report_type (mandatory)**:
either **qweb-pdf** for PDF reports or **qweb-html** for HTML

**report_name** :
the name of your report (which will be the name of the PDF output)

**groups** :
Many2many field to the groups allowed to view/use the current report

**attachment_use** :
if set to True, the report will be stored as an attachment of the record using the name generated by the attachment expression; you can use this if you need your report to be generated only once (for legal reasons, for example)

**attachment** :
python expression that defines the name of the report; the record is acessible as the variable object

Example :

```python
<report
    id="account_invoices"
    model="account.invoice"
    string="Invoices"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="account.report_invoice"
    file="account.report_invoice"
    attachment_use="True"
    attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and
        ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
/>
```

Reference Link : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/reports.html

Comment: I have tried this but it doesnt work i still have the same error :/

Comment: you installed module name "report_webkit" and also python lib of wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: yes i have installed the report_webkit module and the library wkhtmltopdf

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <report
            id="titre_conge_report"
            name="titre_conge"
            auto="False"
            model="hr.holidays"
            file="seetek_leave/report/titre_conge.mako"
            string="Titre de congés"
    parser="seetek_leave.report.titre_conge.titre_conge"
    header="False"
        report_type="webkit"/>
    </data>
</openerp>

Comment: it still not working i had this error: ValueError: Invalid template id: u'titre_conge'

Comment: you have add a template id in `name="<module_name>.<template_id>"` in above example, by namespacing the template id.